# Fail to connect to camera service (RuntimeException) without any good reason

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera, runtimeexception

So my `Manifest.xml` is correct:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>
<application>
...
```

I also release the camera in the `onPause` and `onDestroy` functions,  using this function:

```
private void releaseCamera() {
    // stop and release camera
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }
    //mPreview instance of CameraPreview (referenced below)
    if (mPreview != null) {
        mPreview.setCamera(null);
    }
}
```

I call `mCamera = Camera.open();` only once, during on `onResume`.

Even though I do everything exactly as specified by every example I have found on Stack Overflow and other sources, `Camera.open()` would **occasionally** fail.

Some use cases:

- Open Camera Activity with WiFi enabled (**Camera Works**)
- Open Camera Activity with no network connection (**Camera Fails**) `//Bizarre`
- On catching RuntimeException, then calling `mCamera.takePicture()`, activity crashes and reloads. (**Camera Works**)

So I am completely stumped... Any ideas would be greatly appreciated :D

As requested, find the relevant code below:

### CameraPreiview

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            // create the surface and start camera preview
            if (mCamera != null) {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                mCamera.startPreview();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(VIEW_LOG_TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void refreshCamera(Camera camera) {
        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }
        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }
        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here
        // start preview with new settings
        setCamera(camera);
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(VIEW_LOG_TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.
        refreshCamera(mCamera);
    }

    public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
        //method to set a camera instance
        mCamera = camera;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
        }

    }
}
```

### SampleActivity

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "CameraActivity";

    private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraPreview mPreview;
    private Camera.PictureCallback mPicture;
    private ImageButton capture;
    private Context myContext;
    private LinearLayout cameraPreview;

    // Required to remove the camera if onPause did not
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        releaseCamera();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera_test);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        myContext = this;
        initialize();
    }


    //Code to find the id for the traditional back facing camera
    private int findBackFacingCamera() {
        int cameraId = -1;
        //Search for the back facing camera
        //get the number of cameras
        int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        //for every camera check
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
            Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
            if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
                cameraId = i;
                cameraFront = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return cameraId;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //If there is no camera on the device, inform the user.
        if (!hasCamera(myContext)) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(myContext, "Sorry, your phone does not have a camera!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
        //release the camera if it's in use.
        releaseCamera();
        if (mCamera == null) {
            //if the back facing camera does not exist
            if (findBackFacingCamera() < 0) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No back facing camera found.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                try {
                    //Open the back facing camera, note that Camera.open() gives the same error.
                    mCamera = Camera.open(findBackFacingCamera());
                    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);  //Show in Portrait
                    mPicture = getPictureCallback();
                    mPreview.refreshCamera(mCamera);
                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Could not connect to camera.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public void initialize() {
        cameraPreview = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        mPreview = new CameraPreview(myContext, mCamera);
        cameraPreview.addView(mPreview);

        capture = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
        capture.setOnClickListener(captureListener);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //when on Pause, release camera in order to be used from other applications
        releaseCamera();
    }


    private void captureComplete() {
        //...
    }

    private Camera.PictureCallback getPictureCallback() {
        Camera.PictureCallback picture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                //make a new picture file
                mFile = ImageUtility.getOutputMediaFile(ImageUtility.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
                Log.i(TAG, (mFile == null) + ": ");
                if (mFile == null) {
                    return;
                }

                mPreview.refreshCamera(mCamera);
                mBackgroundHandler.post(new ImageUtility.ImageSaver(getApplicationContext(), data, mFile, new Callable() {
                    @Override
                    public Object call() throws Exception {
                        captureComplete();
                        return null;
                    }
                }));
            }
        };
        return picture;
    }

    View.OnClickListener captureListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mCamera != null) {
                mCamera.autoFocus(new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
                        mPicture = getPictureCallback();
                        mPreview.refreshCamera(camera);
                        camera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                throw new NullPointerException();
            }
        }
    };

    private void releaseCamera() {
        // stop and release camera
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
        if (mPreview != null) {
            mPreview.setCamera(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you testing this on emulator or some real device ? And which API level have you tested it on?

Comment: I am testing it on Hauwei Mate 7, `compileSdkVersion 21, minSdkVersion 14, targetSdkVersion 21`. The device itself is running on API level 19.

Comment: Can you confirm this behavior on other devices? If not, how about an emulator with an emulated camera. If the issue persists then you gotta post your whole code related to camera.

Comment: It has been confirmed to be the same for other devices with the app installed. I'll add the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Some changes you can do, since i had also been working on `Camera` api since 3 months..

In your `CameraPreview` Constructor, add this line

```
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) // add this
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
```

In your `surfaceDestroyed()` method in `CameraPreview` you should remove the callback right after releasing camera resources:

```
this.getHolder().removeCallback(this);
```

Besides changing the above I couldn't figure much out of your `CameraActivity` since you've used AutoFocus and other features.... I used FrameLayout as the container to run the preview in.

Comment: I already do checking for the API level to insure I use a separate Activity for [android.hardware.camera](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) and [android.hardware.camera2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html).

Removing the callback unfortunately didn't do much. My activity is quite simple. I'll add some comments to the code to explain more.